# Unavailable Meta's Prophet at GoogleCloudFunction runtime Python312

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-run, facebook-prophet

At GoogleCloudFunction, below code is unavailable.

```
from prophet import Prophet
model = Prophet()
model.fit(train_data)
```

Its python error is below,

```
RuntimeError: Error during optimization! Command '/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.12/site-packages/prophet/stan_model/prophet_model.bin ...' failed:
```

and Google Cloud Function error is below.

```
Uncaught signal: 11, ..., fault_addr=8.
```

Env info is here.

- Google Cloud Function Gen : 2
- Memory : 2GB
- CPU : 1
- Python runtime : 3.12
- Prophet version : 1.1.5

Anyone who can resolve this issue?
Thank you.

I tried to expand memory upto 32GB for memory problem but it doesn't resolve.
(I already use always-allocated memory.)